# Syncfusion PdfLoadedDocument android exception

Tags: c#, pdf, maui

Under windows everythink works well, but android not. Im try to load pdf form and fill that after.

```
Stream docStream = null;
docStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("sample.pdf");
PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new(docStream);
```

I get Exception "ex = {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. at Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker.get_Length()"

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

I try some staff, but nothing help